# Pandas dataframe aggregating data into counts per group

Tags: pandas, dataframe, group-by, pandas-groupby, aggregate

I'm new to pandas and was looking for some advice on how to reshape my pandas dataframe:

Currently, I have a dataframe like this.

| panelist_id | type | refer_sm | refer_se | refer_non_n |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | HP | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | HP | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | HP | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 1 | PB | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 2 | PB | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 2 | PB | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | HP | 1 | 0 | 0 |

Ideally, I want to group by panelist_id, and aggregate the other columns by count:

| panelist_id | type | type_count | refer_sm_count | refer_se_count | refer_non_n_count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | HP | 2 | 2 | 1 | 1 |
|  | PB | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 2 | HP | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
|  | PB | 2 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |

I've tried using groupby to group by panelist, which works, however I'm a little stuck on the aggregation part. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: ``df.groupby(['panelist_id', 'type']).agg(type_count =('type', 'size'), refer_sm_count=('refer_sm', 'sum'), refer_se_count = ('refer_se', 'sum'))`` ?

Comment: Cool. You could close the question so it doesn't show up as active

Answer (score 0):

df.groupby(['panelist_id', 'type']).agg(type_count =('type', 'size'), refer_sm_count=('refer_sm', 'sum'), refer_se_count = ('refer_se', 'sum')) ?